# cassandra-cli set right after delete in batch mode, set get lost

Tags: cassandra

We have a cassandra (simple) cluster of two nodes.

During a restore from a custom-made dump, we discovered that when we have lines like

```
del column_family['row_1'];
set column_family['row_1']['column1'] = '123';
set column_family['row_1']['column2'] = '456';
set column_family['row_1']['column3'] = '789';
```

... often the first column (column_1) does NOT get set.

We used :

```
$ cassandra-cli -h cassandra.host.name -k keyspace_name -f dump_file
```

We're using cassandra 1.0.10 on a Debian host.

The dump always drop and then recreate the keyspace, so it is actually empty when we execute it. We know that the delete statement is, in fact, not needed.

We removed it but we still can't understand why this happen. I guess this is caused by something that is in this way by design, and that we're just missing, but we can't figure out what EXACTLY is going "wrong".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that what's happening here is that the timestamps for the row tombstone (from the row delete) and one or more of the column writes end up having the same value. Cassandra-cli follows the common convention of using milliseconds for timestamp values, so when the deletion and insertion immediately follow each other like that, it's very possible.

When an inserted column and a tombstone have the same timestamp, the tombstone wins. So it makes sense that your first column would seemingly disappear.

In your case here, the problem would have been solved by writing the deletion with an explicit timestamp, and then writing the other columns with that timestamp plus one. This sort of thing is not normally necessary, but remember, these writes are meant to make it possible for each of them to go to different Cassandra nodes, with the user still being able to get the right results at any time. Timestamp is the conflict resolution mechanism.